# how to stop reading from an excel at a particular row and continue reading from the same excel in ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

i am using ruby watir cucumber framework. I am reading values from an excel, my scenario is

```
Given i am logged in to the console
When i navigate to the "report_link" Report page
When i navigate to the "alert_link" Alerts page
```

my step definitions are

```
When(/^i navigate to the "(.*)" Report page$/) do |report_link|
  book = Spreadsheet.open 'Test.xls' 
  sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
  sheet1.each do |row|
    break if row[0].nil?
    puts row.join(',')
    @browser.link(:href => row[0]).when_present.click
  end
end

When(/^i navigate to the "(.*)" Alerts page$/) do |alert_link|
  book = Spreadsheet.open 'Test.xls' 
  sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
  sheet1.each 4 do |row|
    break if row[5].nil?
    puts row.join(',')
    @browser.link(:href => row[5]).when_present.click
  end
end
```

There are two sets of Href data in my excel. How do i read it from the same excel?

Comment: What does the spreadsheet look like - ie how do you know which rows to read?

Comment: The spreadsheet has jus one column wit multiple rows. the 5th cell is empty. i have hrefs a set of hrefs from cell 1 to 4 and a set of hrefs from cell 6 to 8

Comment: Doesn't that sound hard to maintain? Why not use a column to identify the link type or use multiple spreadsheets?

Comment: I dont want to use multiple spreadsheets, but i can use columns. i tried doing tat and it dint work so i tried with the rows. Can you tell me how i can work with the columns

Comment: I am using this code                                                When(/^i navigate to the "(.*)" Report page$/) do |report_link| 
book = Spreadsheet.open 'Test.xls' 
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0 
sheet1.each do |row| 
break if row[0].nil? 
puts row.join(',') 
@browser.link(:href => row[0]).when_present.click 
end 
end                                                                       Not sure how i can pull values from a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using rows where the list is broken up by a blank line, it would probably be easier to use columns. For example, column A has the report links and column B has the alert links.

Spreadsheet allows you to access columns similar to working with rows. For example, the following will give you the first column:

```
sheet1.column(0)
```

To get all of the values from the column, you can do the following:

```
sheet1.column(0).to_a.compact
#=> Returns an array of cell values
```

The number of rows (ie length of the column) is based on the longest column. In other words, the shorter columns will have extra blank values. The `compact` is added to remove these.

The above could be used in your step like:

```
When(/^i navigate to the "(.*)" Report page$/) do |report_link|
  book = Spreadsheet.open 'Test.xls' 
  sheet1 = book.worksheet 0

  urls = sheet1.column(0).to_a.compact
  urls.each do |url|
    @browser.link(:href => url).when_present.click
  end
end
```

The alert step would be similar - just change the column index.